# Android - Adding a View Programatically Ignores Some Style Attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm adding a button programatically into my existing Android view, when the user taps another button. It's working in terms of functionality, but some of the style information seems to be being ignored.

I'm adding the button by having a separate layout containing just the button, with the style value pre-filled.

`<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/FileStorageDeleteButton"></Button>`

By using `getLayoutInflater`, I'm then able to add this button to the layout.

`buttonDelete = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pete_button_filedelete, null);`

`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutFileStorage);`

`layout.addView(buttonDelete, 1);`

I have an XML file in the values directory which sets the colour, text etc for `@style/FileStorageDeleteButton`, most of which are being used by the button when it's added. But for some reason the four margin attributes and `layout_below` are being ignored.

I'm getting no errors in the LogCat when this button appears, it's as though the styling simply isn't being applied. If I include the button manually in the XML for that layout, it uses all of the styles successfully.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the layout parameters when you call `addView()` because layout parameters are not relevant for a single view, they are always taken in context of the **surrounding view**. There are variants of `addView()` that take a `LayoutParams` argument.

**EDIT Add more details**

You should create a set of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and set your margins in there, then pass that to `addView()`

`layout_below` is ignored for a `LinearLayout` anyway (that attribute is only relevant for a `RelativeLayout`. When you call `addView(buttonDelete, 1)` you are telling it where to put the view in the linear layout.

Comment: Thanks David - your post sent me in the right direction to find that I can pass more variables into inflate. Now using `buttonDelete = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pete_button_filedelete, layout, false);`, though the `layout_below` is still being ignored. I can get around this, but just wondering why that one still isn't working? Thanks again! If I had reputation to upvote you, I would :)

Comment: `layout_below` is only used for a `RelativeLayout`. Your `LinearLayout` ignores this attribute. In a `LinearLayout` you can control above/below by using the position of the View within the layout.